Issues with being a teetotal Baal Teshuva?
I am Baal Teshuva, raised secular and started practicing about 10 years ago. Since then I’ve become significantly more observant, trying to live the best Jewish life I can. I am, however, teetotal- both of my parents are alcoholics and I’ve never been interested in trying it and I probably never will.
I know grape juice can be substituted for most things, but I’m curious if there’s any Halacha that I would not be able to follow with a zero alcohol diet. Any help on the subject would be appreciated!

Getting drunk on Purim comes to mind, but there are workarounds.

Drink grape juice on the Shabbat and festivals, and if you eat way too much, you'll fall asleep on Purim, and some claim that one may rely on that. But the best is to CYLOR.

Yes, that was one of the things my rabbi mentioned when I asked, but he said I could just eat so much I couldn’t stand anymore if I really wanted to partake. He also mentioned the 4 cups of wine on Pesach, since there is a “freedom” aspect with wine that you don’t get from grape juice. I’m just trying to get all of my ducks in a row.

Please find a competent rabbi who understands mental-health issues. There are certainly valid opinions that you don't have to drink at all on Purim, and that grape juice counts at the Seder.

I would say he’s competent, but young- he’s only 26, so he was very up front with speaking from his personal experience. There were multiple things from our discussion today that he said “I’m not sure how I would answer this, let me talk to someone.”

I believe that adding a bit of wine to grape juice is enough - and you wouldn't taste the wine this way. If you are concerned of drinking the whole bottle, you could buy a small one. Regarding Purim, you can take a nap.

@mbloch My Rebbe said you can't just take a nap, you have to drink until you fall asleep. Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky shlit"a holds one can be yotzei drinking on Purim with grape juice.

@N.T. buf it is good enough for the Rema and Mishna Brura, then it sure is good enough for me :->

@mbloch My Rebbe was defining the Rema. "אלא שישתה יותר מלימודו ויישן"
